# How can I start AsyncTask's doInBackground repeatedly when I start the 'A activity'? [complete]

Tags: android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I make the HttpURLConnection to get data from MySQL (android+jsp+MySQL) in my android's AsyncTask.
when I start 'A activity', the first is OK. I can start doInBackground. but when I start the 'A activity' next, I can't start doInBackgound when I start 'A activity' repeatedly.

I want to start doInBackground **whenever I start the 'A activity' repeatedly.**
because I get data from MySQL in doInBackground.

I used to "task.cancel(true)" but this not working.

I'm nuwbe in android, please tell me how to start doInBackground repeatedly.

thank advance.

behind is my code.

oncreate code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_confirm_inventory);
...........
    connectJSP = new getInventoryFromMySQL();
    connectJSP.execute();
...........
}
```

onBackPressed code

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
    } else {
        connectJSP.cancel(true);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

AsyncTask code

```
private class getInventoryFromMySQL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... sId) {
        String sResult = "Error";

        try {
            //URL setting and access
            URL url = new URL("http://-----.com/*****.jsp");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            //setting
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            // connection values
            String sendBicycleName = bicycleName;
            String sendBicycleYear = bicycleYear;

            //StringBuffer
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            buffer.append("sendBicycleName").append("=").append(sendBicycleName).append("&");
            buffer.append("sendBicycleYear").append("=").append(sendBicycleYear);

            //put data into JSP
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
            osw.write(buffer.toString());
            osw.flush();

            //get data from JSP
            InputStreamReader tmp = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(tmp);
            String str;

            //fit the order with JSP(garbage values)
            reader.readLine(); reader.readLine(); reader.readLine(); reader.readLine();
            //get data from JSP
            for(;;) {
                if((str = reader.readLine()) != null && (str != "") && (str != " ") && (str != "null")) {
                    mysqlStoreId[countInventory] = str;
                    for(int c=0; c<5; c++) {
                        for(int s=0; s<8; s++) {
                            str = reader.readLine();
                            mysqlInventory[countInventory][c][s] = Integer.parseInt(str);
                        }
                    }
                    countInventory++;
                } else if(str == null && str == "null") {
                    //finish for if values equals null
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sResult;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer. I check all code's log.
the problem is that 'doInBackground' have an error. there is no an else in 'for(;;)' so AsyncTack make 'onCancelled()'. but I'm not write the 'onCancelled()' code.

when I add onCancelled(), I can cancel(true) and re-start the Asynctask.

Thank!